# Fuzziness in phrase matching in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How to include fuzziness in phrase matching ? In the elasticsearch documentation it is mentioned that  fuzziness is not supported with phrase matching.
I have documents containing phrases now i have a text body , now i want to find out the common phrases of text and phrases within the documents , but need to search phrases that might be spelled wrong .

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do this:

1. Remove Whitespace and index the hole Phrase as one Token (I think there is a Filter for that in Elastic). In your query you would have to do the same.
2. There is a Tokenizer where I forgot the name (Maybe someone can help out here?) which lets you index more than one words together. If your phrases have a common maximum length like 5 words or so this could do the trick.

Beware fuzzi only works for a maximum distance of 2 so if you have a very long sentence 2 might not be enough and you have to split it.